# how do i print three boxes one behind other in css

Tags: css, flexbox, box

So let say i have three images same height and width a, b, c. I want a to come in front with full size after than b with a bit small and left part should be covered behind a . and then c smaller than b  left part cover by b right side.

i tried using positioning in these boxes like absolute, relative , fixed but in vain

`.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div class="rcorners1">
        <div class="text"><h1>Digital Card Details</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rcorners2">
        <div class="left-wrapper">
          <img class="image1" src="./images/Page1.jpg" alt="failed" />

          <img class="image2" src="./images/Page2.jpg" alt="failed" />

          <img class="image3" src="./images/Page3.jpg" alt="failed" />
        </div>
        <!-- <a href=""></a> -->
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

`.css`

```
.rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 70px;
  /* background: #73ad21; */
  background-image: url(./images/Background.jpg);
  padding: 20px;
  /* flex: auto; */
  width: 950px;
  height: 250px;
}

.rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  /* border: brown; */
  /* background-image: url(./images/Background.jpg); */
  padding: 20px;
  /* float: none; */
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin-top: -150px;
  /* flex: auto; */
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}

.leftWrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  height: 650px;
}
.image1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 260px;
  padding: auto;
  height: 380px;
  margin: 1px;
  /* padding: 4px; */
  border: 4px solid white;
  margin-left: -200px;
  outline-style: groove;
  outline-color: brown;
}

.image2 {
  /* position: absolute; */
  border: 4px solid white;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  /* padding: auto; */
  outline-style: groove;
  outline-color: brown;
  /* outline-width: 12px; */
  /* border: 1px green solid; */
  margin-bottom: 38px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.image3 {
  width: 150px;
  /* position: relative; */
  outline-style: groove;
  border: 4px solid white;
  /* outline-color: brown; */
  height: 220px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  padding: auto;

  margin-bottom: 100px;
  /* margin-left: px; */
}
```

Output -
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moMYa.png)

But i want something like
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nti2N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is starting to look like your "expected": https://codepen.io/kodmunki/pen/wvyJPbV

```html
<div class="continer">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.a,.b,.c {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000aa;
  z-index: 3;
}

.b {
  top: 20px;
  left: 65px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #ffff00aa;
  z-index: 2;
}

.c {
  top: 30px;
  left: 125px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff00ffaa;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/mohit-04/pen/abWPwPq i tried but it doesn't able to work . Its just coming in reverse order

Comment: I took the time to write up a pen for you @AndroidArmy. You may need to play with your top, left, width, height, opacity and background-image or change the contained <div> to <img>, but the principles are there evidenced by the output of the pen juxtaposed to the "expected" link you shared. For you to get your "output" you are going to have to make a few minor tweaks and you're there. Maybe 30sec to 2min of work. Good luck!